# How to get a File using MediaStore.Downloads for a file in the Downloads directory?

Tags: android

The documentation says `MediaStore.Downloads` can be used, but it does not have any example of reading a downloaded file. All the examples I could find on the internet were about downloading and saving files using `MediaStore.Downloads`, but all I want is reading an already downloaded file.

Let's say that I drag-and-dropped "sample.epub" file into the Android emulator. It is saved to the "Downloads" directory by the emulator. Now, how can I get a `File` of this "sample.epub" so that I can pass it to [the constructor of the `ZipFile` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#constructor.summary)?

Comment: Android version of emulator?

Answer (score -2):

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "sample_epub");
```

This gives you a nice File object.

You can pass it to the ZipFile class but on Android 11+ devices it will not have read access. So File class of little use.

Comment: I believe this might not work properly on Android 11 and above. 
You are allowed to write files in Downloads folder but File.listFiles() will return only files created by your application.